# I was trying to make this circuit on Proteus but this error appears

Tags: transistors, mosfet, capacitor, transformer, proteus

I was trying to make this circuit in Proteus as you can see but
"[SPICE] transient GMIN stepping at time=3.12737e-007"
error keeps appearing. How do I make this error go away?

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1]]

[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Use center tapped transformer. Also left node of C1, bottom of R1,gate of Q2, collector of Q1 are all connected together, same on other side.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem I see is there is no ground at all, spice needs a ground and there needs to be grounds on both sides of the transformer (or it makes the system of equations very hard to solve).

Comment: This is a very likely answer. Proteus gets super confused when there is no defined GND